# Is there a built-in feature in Azure Cosmos DB to archive data?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to avoid DOcumentDB Data migration tool to archive data that hasn't been modified over a year. Is there any built-in feature like TTL to archive the data?

Comment: There isn't a built in feature. This question has been asked before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035602/cosmosdb-archive-data-older-than-n-years-into-cold-storage - it's worth checking out that post and seeing if you have any further questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cosmosdb - archive data older than n years into cold storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035602/cosmosdb-archive-data-older-than-n-years-into-cold-storage)